# Unicodeerror when using tika parse.from_file with django filefield

Tags: python, django-views, apache-tika

I'm getting the following error when trying to parse a file(tried docx and pdf) from a django fileupload form using tika:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

forms.py

```
class UpLoad(Form):
file = FileField(label="Upload doc here:")
```

views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UpLoad(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        doc = form.cleaned_data['file'].read()
        text_dict = parser.from_file(doc)
        text = text_dict['content']
```

The error is triggered when the tika method (parser) is called. I'm assuming the error is triggered because I am using the form cleaned data variable, and most tutorials I can find tells me I need a file path.

How do I transform the cleaned data so it can be parsed properly?

EDIT: error log below:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/opprett_kandidat/7

Django Version: 3.2.7
Python Version: 3.9.10
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'Tekstanalyseapp',
 'microsoft_auth',
 'active_link',
 'bootstrap5']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\larsl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\larsl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\larsl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\larsl\OneDrive\Skrivebord\Puls-R\Applikasjon\Sorting-Hat\Tekstanalyseapp\views.py", line 145, in opprett_kandidat
    analysetekst_dict = parser.from_file(dokument)
  File "C:\Users\larsl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tika\parser.py", line 40, in from_file
    output = parse1(service, filename, serverEndpoint, headers=headers, config_path=config_path, requestOptions=requestOptions)
  File "C:\Users\larsl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tika\tika.py", line 327, in parse1
    path, file_type = getRemoteFile(urlOrPath, TikaFilesPath)
  File "C:\Users\larsl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tika\tika.py", line 762, in getRemoteFile
    urlp = urlparse(urlOrPath)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 392, in urlparse
    url, scheme, _coerce_result = _coerce_args(url, scheme)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 128, in _coerce_args
    return _decode_args(args) + (_encode_result,)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 112, in _decode_args
    return tuple(x.decode(encoding, errors) if x else '' for x in args)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 112, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(x.decode(encoding, errors) if x else '' for x in args)

Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError at /opprett_kandidat/7
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Note: The names used in the example code above are a bit different from the ones in the error log. I modified them a bit for readability. Let me know if I the error log is hard to understand due to this, and I will modify it.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: error shows problem with byte `0xb5` - code `b'\xb5'.decode('utf-8')` raises error but `b'\xb5'.decode('latin1')` gives me char `'µ'` (micro) - maybe your file has chars in `latin1` and you should set it somewhere in `parser`

Comment: code `b'\xb5'.decode('cp1250')` also gives `'µ'`

Comment: Error log added. I also noticed that I forgot to add the .read() after the cleaned data.